# Seagate hdd (internal) unmount/disappear after awhile i plugged in

Tags: data-recovery, freeze, lag, hard-drive-failure

**Summary:**

Before my Seagate ST1000DM003 (1TB) failed, the disk usage always goes up to 100% active with no transfer rate, this causing my pc freeze randomly. BIOS POST shows up'S.M.A.R.T. COMMAND FAILED', but i  ignored it. Few days later i can't boot windows anymore. When i'm trying to access it, it will completely disappear from my pc even bios, but it's still spinning. i have to restart or wait some time then only it will appear again. Someone said that it was known issue. check this out: [url]http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17241/~/known-issues-with-seagate-barracuda-7200.14-desktop-drives[/url]
Unfortunately, the firmware update failed. Is there any other way that i can update my firmware? if yes, you can guide me with steps?
I also tried to recover my data with Gnu ddrescue, the process failed too.

---

**Detail:**

Last two week, i'm facing lag issue on my computer, something like the applications takes some time to open up, and my pc freeze randomly. When i take a look at my task manager, my disk 0 (primary drive which with the windows installed in) goes up to 100% active when i'm trying to open up an application, then drop back to normal percentage after that.

7 days later, the BIOS POST hold for 1 min or longer before booting windows, and it also shows up'S.M.A.R.T. COMMAND FAILED', but i pressed 'F1' to resume booting, and when windows booted successfully, windows is so lag until i can't do anything. Task manager shows that the Disk 0 is always active at 100%, all the time even there is no transfer rate. Finally i can't boot windows anymore.

Then i installed a new windows in my secondary HDD in order to fix the problem with my primary HDD. Every time i'm trying to mount the HDD and recover my data in it, it will mount first but i still can't access it, it just like loading the file. After some time, it unmount and completely disappear from my pc, even i couldn't find it in device manager and BIOS, but it's still spinning.

I found that someone was saying that it was known issue with the model of hdd. check this out: http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17241/~/known-issues-with-seagate-barracuda-7200.14-desktop-drives 
Unfortunately, the firmware update failed, tried for 5 times. By default, i make a bootable usb with the firmware, and boot it up. sometimes the software couldn't detect my hdd, but when it finally detected the hdd, the update still failed. Is there any other way that i can update my firmware? if yes, you can guide me with steps?

I also tried to recover my data with Gnu ddrescue, the process failed too. Thanks for reading it, sorry for my bad english. appreciate your help

---

**P.S.**

- Hdd doesn't have clicking sound, i think that's the problem with logical damage.
- I also faced this issue last time, then it resolved when i formatted it and installed new windows again. But i want the data back this time.
- Will this problem occur if i didn't defrag my hdd for a long time?

System: Windows 8.1 Pro

HDD: Seagate ST1000DM003 (1TB)

Comment: It was very unlikely to be anything you did or didn't do yourself - unfortunately those Seagate drives have a catastrophic failure rate… but that's what backups are for.

Comment: Welcome here on SuperUser. It's great to see that you gave us a lot of information about your situation and what you have (not) tried. Because this results in a lot of text, I'd like to suggest to add a summary at the beginning of your question. This might get more people interested in reading (and maybe even answering) your question. Also: please check the links in your question; they don't seem to be working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble recovering data from an older Seagate HD](http://superuser.com/q/929138)

Comment: I've had a drive behave similarly before it died - it was a model that had a high failure rate due to firmware issues. This is why backups are useful. If the drive dosen't have any massively critical data, and is under warranty, and RMA might be your best option.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm having problem with my Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 1000Gb which is different from Seagate Barracuda 7200.11 500Gb.

Comment: @agtoever added summary about my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure this is hardware problem, not even firmware bugs, try to check the SMART of HDD before it get randomly unmounted. If the SMART value is NORMAL, possible this is PCB board problem, you can RMA if still in warranty period but vendor WILL NOT keep your existing data. If you want to recover the existing data, you have to ask for some recovery store for help to replace the PCB board, the parts of PCB board is around 40 USD (not included labor cost) for common HDD.